# Почему phpMyAdmin не показывает базу данных

Tags: sql, django, база-данных

В общем так получилось что в phpmyadmin не показывает базу данных от сайта, а каким образом её импортировать я не знаю, скажу сразу что регистрировался на phpmyadmin через хостинг так как по другому не понял как(возможно по этому и нет базы данных но это только моё предположение), пока выводит только две базы одну от хостинга которая соответственно пустая, а другую даже не знаю от чего но она заполнена, но как я понял та вряд ли от сайта. Пробовал импортировать но вся загвоздка в том что я даже не знаю что и откуда импортировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Не судите строго так как с базой данных работаю впервые.

Answer (score 0):

В общем всё оказалось довольно просто, просто нужно было зарегистрироватся с именем root без пароля так откроется база данных компа а не хостинга.